# DataTables: Add option on which script to run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am showing a DataTables using the below code. It is using server side processing and works ok.

I would like to add a drop down option above the table with for example:

- Product Group 1
- Product Group 2

and then based on the selected option this determines what server side processing script is run.

**Existing code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table').dataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                    "url": "../server_processing/prices.php",
                    "type": "POST"
                    },
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
            "serverSide": true
        } );

        var tabletools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table, {
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "sSwfPath": "../copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        } );

        $( tabletools.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');
    } );
</script>
```

For example here the `"url": "../server_processing/prices.php",`would be `"url": "../server_processing/prices.php?ProductGroup=X",`.

I'm sure something like this is simple in JavaScript/jQuery but I'm not sure how to start. I am new to both, my only experience thus far has been DataTables.

Also how would I handle the HTML table itself as the column headers could change based on the selected product group.

**Existing code**

```
  <table id="table" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Price Table</th>
              <th>Product Code</th>
              <th>Product Description</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

this is correct for Product Group 1, but Product Group 2 might require an additional column header for example.

I understand the easier option is to just create 2 pages and have 2 tables but I don't want that.

I hope I've explained clearly enough, if more details are needed etc. I can help. Appreciate any help from the experts!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can use `fnReloadAjax` as shown below
HTML -

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">Product Group 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product Group 2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table').dataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                    "url": "../server_processing/prices.php",
                    "type": "POST"
                    },
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
            "serverSide": true
        } );

        var tabletools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table, {
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "sSwfPath": "../copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        } );

        $( tabletools.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');

        //on change event handle for select box
        $('#select1').on("change", function(){
          var value = $(this).val();
          table.fnReloadAjax( '../server_processing/prices.php?ProductGroup='+value );
        });
    } );
```